# Using a Treeview with Checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, treeview

I have `treeView` that has several `Nodes` like this

```
Question 1
Question 2
Question 3
Question 4
```

Inside each of those node there are 4 `checkboxes` - `Answer A, Answer B, Answer C, Answer D`, depending on whichever checkbox is clicked the text of a Node will change to `Question1 - A,B,C,D`. The answer to the question could mean all,one,two,three or none of the `checkboxes` are clicked.
What im trying to do is remove the letter if a `checkbox` is `unchecked`
My Code:

```
private void ckbAnswerA_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        updateAnswerA();
    }
void updateAnswerA()
    {
        var words = new List<string>();


        if (ckbOption1.Checked)
        {
            words.Add("A,");
            treeView1.SelectedNode.Text += string.Join(" ", words);
        }
```

Etc for the other `checkBoxes`...

The Code above works fine when `selecting` a `checkBoxes` but not when `deselecting`

Comment: I just noticed something that wasn't in the previous question, you are adding the text after each check whereas it should be done after all boxes have been checked!

Comment: ok, do you mean putting all the If Statements in one method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually way, I hope you get the idea.

```
private void ckbAnswerA_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ckbAnswerA.Checked)
    {
        updateAnswerA(true);
    }
    else
    {
        updateAnswerA(false);
    }
}

private void updateAnswerA(bool flag)
{
    if(flag)
    {
        var words = new List<string>();
        words.Add("A,");
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Text += string.Join(" ", words);
    }
    else
    {
        string update = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
        update = update.Replace("A,", "");
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Text = update;
    }
}
```